# Question about new behavior of current connection combobox in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a question about the new behavior of the database selection combobox in SQL Server 2012 (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to move your focus to it). It seems that, unlike in SQL Server 2008 R2, clicking in the text of the database selected (as opposed to the dropdown arrow) selects the text in the combobox rather than activating the dropdown function.

I find this sort of a nuisance, since the new intellisense isn't active in the combobox. I don't actually want to type out the name of the database since most of the databases have the same prefix in their name; that would be a lot of unnecessary typing.

As such, I would prefer if clicking the text of the combobox would activate the dropdown rather than have it be available for text input. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Also, if I use the <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> keyboard shortcut to put the focus on the combobox, is there any key I can press to activate the dropdown so I can navigate to the available databases that way? I know pressing up and down will switch from one to another, but is there anyway to actually bring up the list?

Can anyone recommend any options to alter the behavior of the combo box to make it more useful? I was considering using SSMSBoost; does anyone have any experience with it?

I would appreciate any advice anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> (focus the combobox) and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> - this will make the combobox drop down.

Comment: and thanks for mentioning my project SSMSBoost !! :)